# placement new c++

Tags: c++

Пример взят частично с [Википедии](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/New_(C%2B%2B)#Placement_new)

```
std::string *mas = reinterpret_cast<std::string*>(new char[10 * sizeof(std::string)]);
delete[] mas;
```

Не важно `reinterpret_cast` (static или другое) вылетает ошибка `BLOCK_TYPE_IS_VALID`.
То же поведение при `operator new[] (10*sizeof(std::string))`.

Как правильно размещать динамические данные побайтно? Так понимаю ошибка в выравнивании? Или не в ту сторону копаю.

```
operator delete[] (mas);
```

Удалять надо правильно. Время позднее туплю. Так нормальное поведение. Знатоки в чём проблема для обычного `delete[]`?

Comment: Для STL копать нужно в сторону аллокаторов.

Comment: Что вы хотите сделать?

Comment: @Cerbo https://stepic.org/lesson/%D0%A8%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%BD%D1%8B-%D0%BA%D0%BB%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%B2-563/step/8?course=%D0%9F%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%BC%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%BD%D0%B0-%D1%8F%D0%B7%D1%8B%D0%BA%D0%B5-C%20%20&unit=886 я решил через обычные указатели. много звездочек))). решаю теперь через википедию через умные штуки, скажем так

Comment: @Cerbo 
python + java убивают мысли старого порядочного кода. с & c++ для души, баловство.вот и решил вспомнить, оказалась в моих мозгах free(my_memory).на плюсах прогал до нашей эры))но душа просит)

Comment: А откуда взялся placement new, где он в вашем вопросе?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Там же [на степике] в лекции вроде доходчиво рассказано...

А так, да, операция `new`/`new[]` состоят из двух действий: собственно аллокации памяти и вызова конструктора. Эти два действия можно разделить вызвав отдельно `operator new (size_t size)`/`operator new[] (size_t size)` - для аллокакации памяти и, собственно, placement new (`new (ptr) Type(ctor_args...)`), что бы вызвать конструктор и создать объект.

Собственно вручную потом придётся и разрушать объект. Т.е. вызывать деструктор вручную:

```
ptr->~Type();
```

После чего очистить память при помощи `operator delete (ptr)/operator delete[] (ptr)`

Когда вы смешиваете placement new и разрушение при помощи delete, вы сами себе пытаетесь выстрелить в ногу. Ровно как и в обратном направлении.

К примеру, при вызове `new[]` может аллоцироваться памяти больше чем запрошено (в нюансы работы аллокаторов вдаваться не будем) и объекты конструируются не с начала блока памяти, а с некоторого отступа и возвращается значение указателя на этот отступ. А в зарезервированное место сохраняется в т.ч. количество объектов в массиве: эта информация может использоваться потом `delete[]` что бы правильно понять - сколько деструкторов нужно вызывать. Как это будет реализовано в конкретном компиляторе - вопрос реализации. Но поэтому нельзя мешать `new`/`delete[]` и `new[]`/`delete`: форма оператора помогает компилятору сделать правильные выводы о структуре памяти. По той же причине нельзя мешать placement new и `delete`/`delete[]` - в общем случае размещающий new может быть вызван для блока памяти который аллоцировался каким-то пользовательским способом: из какой-то системной области, из пула, из какого-то кастомного аллокатора и т.д. `delete` после разрушения объекта ещё и попытается освободить её. Что при этом будет - одному Ктулху известно. А `delete[]` ещё может предположить какую-то свою структуру и начать оперировать с невалидным указателем.

В общем - будьте симметричны.

Answer (score 2):

Оператор `new` не только выделяет память, но и вызывает конструктор или конструкторы для созданного или созданных (в случае массива) объектов.

При вызове оператора `delete` вызываются соответственно деструкторы этих объектов.

Однако в вашем фрагменте кода нигде конструктор класса `std::string` не вызывается. Поэтому выделенная память не инициализирована соответствующим образом. В результате чего оператор `delete` имеет неопределенное поведение.

Comment: а operator delete[] ... не вызывает получается в данном случае?

Comment: explicit Array(size_t size = 0, const T& value = T()){
  mas = reinterpret_cast <T*>(operator new[] (size * sizeof(T)));
  this->size_ = size;
  for (size_t i=0; i<size; ++i){
   new (mas + i) T(value);
  }
 }
и вопрос разве в этом случае конструктор не вызывается?// решение конструтора для шаблонов

Comment: стоило брать код из википедии полностью, вы оттуда вырезали собственно placement new.

`operator delete[]` не вызывает деструктор, `delete` вызывает.

Comment: @sercxjo поведение оператора и было интересно. С Вами согласен, в свое время мне говорили взял Нюрку за ляшку, то за ляшку и отпускай (грубый пример), и когда брал за ляшку, а отпускал за сиську получал указкой по затылку))) вот и вопрос почему так нельзя??? наверное это си ++

Comment: Нельзя потому что деструктор расчитан на то что ранее был вызван конструктор.
Этот пример в википедии не для начинающих, а для особых случаев. Если нужно разместить данные не в обычной динамической памяти а в заранее заданном месте или в каком-то другом блоке памяти (например в памяти отображённой на файл). При этом сначала выделяется память, потом в цикле вручную вызываются конструкторы для неё с помощью особой формы new с дополнительным аргументом. И далее показано как обратно всё освобождать в таком случае.